# How is this 1950's DC blower motor with 2 black wires and 2 red wires supposed to be wired?

Tags: dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor

My brother bought an old Flxible Visicoach and it came with this DC blower motor for the heater:

[image: DC Motor Plate]

I've searched (appears to be a GE 5BN56LA15) but can't find a mention of it anywhere.  I've torn it apart and cleaned it and it seems to be in really good shape, I'm pretty sure we could wire it up and make it work (there's also 1.5 ohm rheostat with massive ceramic heatsink for controlling the fan speed).

But I wanted some feedback about exactly how it's supposed to be driven.  When the heater is on, the rheostat connects the "BAT" terminal to the "FIELD" terminal.  The other side of the rheostat is labeled "ARM"ature.  So the field is always energized and the speed is controlled by varying the armature voltage.  Simple enough.

The concern is the motor has 4 wires - 2 black and 2 red, as below.

[image: 4-Wire DC Motor]

Is it as simple as tying the black and red on the left side of the schematic to GND, the remaining black wire to "Field" and the remaining red to ARMature?  (And swapping a red or black pair if needed to get the correct direction.)  The colors make that solution feel a little uncomfortable...

Anyway, that would be my guess, but then I saw fancy wiring options like these:
[image: DC Motor Wiring Options]

And I wonder if there might be a reason it has 4 wires instead of 2.

Update: Here's the fan speed control by request:
[image]

Comment: (Wiring options (d)&(e) are for compound wound machines, (c) is the reversed direction wiring Jasen mentions. (Shunt operated as (b) - universal motors/series operated are weird at low mechanical loads.))

Comment: `field is always energized and the speed is controlled by varying the armature voltage`/current. Which is weird considering the "field power" is lower by about one order of magnitude. But wait, with the rheostat connecting "BAT" to "FIELD", it *does* seem to control the field winding: can you show the labelling?

Comment: I've added (and triple-checked) the labeling of the speed control.  I *think* what Jasen suggested to change direction was still B, just with either the field or the armature connections reversed, otherwise it's a series connection (which might still work?  I don't know).

Comment: My bad, didn't look beyond *F connected to other terminal of A* to recognise *series*. Thinking about it, it may be difficult to connect the other terminal to anything but chassis/ground.

Answer (score 3):

it says that it's shunt wound, so  it's pattern `(b)` above,

The motor will spin in a different direction depending on which way you pair the black and red wires; so 4 wires gives you the option to reverse the motor.